# A counterexample to $f_{n}\xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_{L^{1}}}f$ implies $f_{n}\xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_{C^{0}}}f$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$\|f\|_{L^{1}}\le\|f\|_{C^{0}}$ so $f_{n}\xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_{C^{0}}}f$ implies $f_{n}\xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_{L^{1}}}f$. I want to prove the converse is false but cannot come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\ge2$ let
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n\,x & \text{if }0\le x\le1/n, \\ 2-n\,x & \text{if }1/2<x<2/n, \\0 & \text{if }2/n\le x\le1.\end{cases}
$$
Then $f_n\to0$ in $L^1$, pointwise, but not uniformly.

Comment: @Julián_Aguirre So uniform convergence implies convergence in $C^{0}$?